# Should the input form be updated automatically after making associations to request for value of the foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I generated two Active record models called User and Job.
I made an association between the two where:
User belongs_to :Job 
Job has_many:User
I can confirm this worked since I can see a foreign id column (job_id) in the users table. However, when ever I go to http://localhost:3000/users/new to create a new user record, the only Inputs form I see are Name and Email (which are the other columns I have on the users table) and I can not see any Job input form to enter value for job id. Whenever I try to create a new user record I get an error message saying 1 error prohibited this user from being saved:Job must exist 
Is this how the Active record model should be like when I make a new association to a model? Do I have to manually change the user_params inside users_controller.rb or do I change somewhere else? 
I'm asking this question because the tutorial I was following made it look as if the form should automatically change to include the foreign keys.

Comment: As the error says, since there is a reference and for creating a user, you need to have a job. Either if you are using `Rails 5`, you can make the `belongs_to :optional` else if you're using `Rails < 5`, then put a `dropdown` which says something like `Job.all`, where you select a job for a user and send that to the controller as params and save the user.

Comment: could you expand on what you mean by dropdown which says something like Job.all, Im new. Also I don't want to make it optional since I want to force user to input an id number

Comment: As per your association every `user belongs_to job`, meaning in the dropdown, you can either show the `title` of the job or the `id` which the user will select. Can you update your question with the schema.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted by using generate scaffold_controller and regenerated the entire controller and view whilst keeping the model the same.
In my case I run 
rails generate scaffold_controller user name:string email:string job_id:int